# Java Get Link From Another Class (Json)

Tags: java, json, webview

I have a WebView and I want to get this WebView's link from another class.
My another class gets this link from JSON data. Would you help me please? I am new at Java :/

Main.java;

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                engine.load("https://www.google.com");
            }
        });
```

Reader.java (Link is in here)

```
public class Readerr {
    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cs3x6");
        String Link = json.get("link").toString();
    }
}
```